# Android music listview

Tags: java, android

My app searches the sd card and displays the songs but when I click on the song it does not play nor does it crash.What should I add to the code to make it play. There is no error shown in the adb trace.

```
 private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private String[] mMusicList;
private String[] mAudioPath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medias);
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mMusicList = getAudioList();

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMusicList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            try {
                playSong(mMusicList[arg2]);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private String[] getAudioList() {
    final Cursor mCursor=getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, null, null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

    int count = mCursor.getCount();
    String[] songs = new String[count];
    String[] mAudioPath = new String[count];
    int i = 0;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            songs[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            mAudioPath[i] = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
            i++;
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    mCursor.close();

    return songs;
}

private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalStateException, IOException {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString();

    path = extStorageDirectory + File.separator + path;

    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The path string you are passing to mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path) is wrong...

Return "mAudioPath" array instead of "songs" array in getAudioList() method and change playSong() method like this..

```
private void playSong(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException {
    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```